# Replace $ with word "dollar"

Tags: linux, sed

I have this string:

"I want to pay $200 for the service"

I want it to become:

"I want to pay 200 dollars for the service"

So maybe sed or awk command to remove the $ symbol and add the word "dollar" after the 200 amount.

Comment: no fractional dollar amounts allowed?

Comment: Yeah we can ignore fractional amounts, the solution from ajbw works great.

Answer (score 3):

You can use sed:

```
> echo '"I want to pay $200 for the service"' | sed 's/\$\([0-9]\+\)/\1 dollars/'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ✍
"I want to pay 200 dollars for the service"
```

This won't handle the `$1` case (it will still say `dollars`, not `dollar`).  Works on GNU sed 4.5.  Add the `g` flag if you want it to work for multiple occurrences.